# Wrong PHP Value from Controller to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my test controller

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    $data2 = array('name' => 'God', 'age' => -1);
    return json_encode($data2);
}
```

And this is ajax request(url is correct)

```
$(".simple").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'register',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("fail");
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
});
```

Why do I get 'fail'? And `jqXHR.responseText` is empty.

Comment: What status code do you get? What does the response actually look like? What do you get if you visit the URL manually?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Is anything actually calling the PHP function `actionRegister()`? Please show us the missing pieces of code here. Also, what's the php file name for the code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling that PHP function on `register.php`?

Moreover, for Ajax you should use `echo` and not `return`.

So I would do

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $data2 = array( 'name' => 'God', 'age' => -1 );
    echo json_encode($data2);
}
```

and then call it from `register.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying the dataType as json, the ajax call will fail if the returned string is not valid json. And since your responseText is empty, its very likely that the PHP is not getting executed the way you think.

In your AJAX call you specify the url as 'register'. It should probably 'register.php' ,right?